# SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 not working in Sequelize migration

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Here is my function:

```
up: queryInterface => {
  return queryInterface.sequelize.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0')
   .then(() => queryInterface.dropTable('my_table'));
},
```

This query works in the table:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`;
```

The error is

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: I have no clue about sequelize, but as a DBA I can tell you, that the `set foreign_key_checks=0` statement has session scope. If possible, just execute the two statements in the same session.

Comment: @fancyPants It seems you can't execute two statements in the same session. I removed references from other tables and it worked.

Comment: Is something/someone else working in the database at the same time? If yes, then removing references can't be the solution. That's also why I downvoted Zendem's answer.

Comment: I didn't notice that there were two tables, which reference mine. I removed columns from them and it worked. SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 is unsafe.

Comment: You rather have no referential integrity at all? And you remove columns? Okay then. Have a nice day.

Comment: In this migration, I needed to remove a table. So yes, references aren't needed anymore. Have a nice day.

Comment: Not working for me too :(

Comment: @BartusZak The way I see things is sequelize uses different threads for each query, therefore dropTable has FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1. Instead of setting FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, which is not safe, you need to remove all references  to your table from the other tables and then drop it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a constraint/foreignKey in Sequelize migration, you need use this:

```
// an example of table projects and users
await queryInterface.removeConstraint('projects', 'projects_ibfk_1'); // tableName, constraintId
await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
```

Is better that execute 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0'.

If you don't know constraint ids (in my case is projects_ibfk_1), use:

```
const refs = await queryInterface.getForeignKeyReferencesForTable('projects');
console.log(refs);
```